# How can i store Custom types in QSettings?

Tags: qt

From API docs:

> Custom types registered using qRegisterMetaType() and 
>   qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators() can be stored using QSettings.

How can I do that? I get the error:

> too few template-parameter-lists at `qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators`

My code:

```
class LineUser {
public:
    int uId;
    QString passwd;
    qint8 statusType;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(LineUser)
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const LineUser &myObj) {
    out<<myObj.uId<<myObj.passwd<<myObj.statusType;
    return out;
}
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, LineUser &myObj) {
    in>>myObj.uId>>myObj.passwd>>myObj.statusType;
    return in;
}
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<LineUser>("LineUser");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators` is a function, not a macro.

You need to call it from a .cpp file, e.g. in your main() method

Comment: thank you... But it create a new error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'stream << * t'...

Comment: Try defining the operator functions in the main.cpp as well.. before the call of operator <<

Comment: Probably you also need to `#include <QMetaType>` if you haven't done that

Comment: Hard to tell, are you maybe trying to store a LineUser* (pointer) instead of a LineUser object? You could also open a new question with that new error if you want

Comment: Thank you very much , i have resolve it.. QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const LineUser &myObj);
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, LineUser &myObj); make these function friend...